# JUnit test difference between assertEquals() and Assert.assertEquals()

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, junit, assert

I made a method to count occurrence of a given character in String.

```
public Integer numberOf(String str, Character a){}
```

I tried to test as normal using:

```
@Test
public void test1(){
    Integer result = oc.numberOf("Lungimirante", 'u');
    Assert.assertEquals(1, result);
}
```

but Eclipse complains it.

I googled and I found that to test it I needed use:

```
assertEquals(1, result); //it works correctly
```

instead of: `Assert.assertEquals(1, result);`

Could you explain me why? What is the difference?

Comment: The `assert[Equals,etc.]` method invocations come from a static import of the `junit.framework.Assert` class (or `org.junit.Assert` etc.). Likely you have an `import static  junit.framework.Assert.*` or similar statement, but you haven't actually imported `junit.framework.Assert`.

Comment: @Mena: yes to use `assertEquals` I imported: `import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;`
and before to use `Assert.assertEquals`only import `org.junit.Assert;`

Comment: I hate autoboxing and this is one of the reasons why. Getting `NullPointerExceptions` where you won't expect them is another. Because of this I configured Eclipse to see occurrences of autoboxing as error (and IMHO it speaks for itself that there is an option for this, that I'm not that wrong with my opinion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't provide any details for this:

> Eclipse complains it.

I suspect it is an `Ambiguous method call` ...

[image]

... which is caused by there being multiple 'forms' of `assertEquals` some of which take int, some long, some Object, some String etc etc.

So, you just need to be explicit about which one you want to use. For example, both of the following `assertEquals` calls compile because they are explicit about the **type** of the `expected` and `actual` argument:

```
Integer result = oc.numberOf("Lungimirante", 'u');
Assert.assertEquals(new Integer(1), result);
Assert.assertEquals(1, result.intValue());
```

Comment: :the complain: _The method assertEquals(Object, Object) is ambiguous for the type Assert_

Comment: @SwampThing yes, that's what I assumed so my answer is relevant to your question. Just tweak your `assertEquals` invocations (using the examples supplied in my answer) so that you are being clear about the type of the `expected` and `actual` arguments.